# Some files not copying in installation folder the first time using WIX

Tags: c#, wpf, wix

Recently I'm using WIX to create an installer for my WPF application and I need to copy lots of dll's into the installation folder. The problem is that, some of them are not being copied into the folder the first time I use the installer, but it does the second time. This occurs when an older version of the software is already installed in the computer.

```
<!-- Telerik Dlls -->
  <Component Id="Telerik.Windows.Controls.Chart.dll" Guid="8bd4b407-1ecb-40d7-b4c3-000000000014">
    <File Id="Telerik.Windows.Controls.Chart.dll" Source="..\..\bin\vc100\Win32\Release\Telerik.Windows.Controls.Chart.dll" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes"/>
  </Component>
  <Component Id="Telerik.Windows.Controls.Data.dll" Guid="8bd4b407-1ecb-40d7-b4c3-000000000015">
    <File Id="Telerik.Windows.Controls.Data.dll" Source="..\..\bin\vc100\Win32\Release\Telerik.Windows.Controls.Data.dll" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes"/>
  </Component>
  <Component Id="Telerik.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.dll" Guid="8bd4b407-1ecb-40d7-b4c3-000000000016">
    <File Id="Telerik.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.dll" Source="..\..\bin\vc100\Win32\Release\Telerik.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.dll" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes"/>
  </Component>
  <Component Id="Telerik.Windows.Controls.dll" Guid="8bd4b407-1ecb-40d7-b4c3-000000000017">
    <File Id="Telerik.Windows.Controls.dll" Source="..\..\bin\vc100\Win32\Release\Telerik.Windows.Controls.dll" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes"/>
  </Component>
  <Component Id="Telerik.Windows.Controls.Docking.dll" Guid="8bd4b407-1ecb-40d7-b4c3-000000000018">
    <File Id="Telerik.Windows.Controls.Docking.dll" Source="..\..\bin\vc100\Win32\Release\Telerik.Windows.Controls.Docking.dll" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes"/>
  </Component>

<!-- Modules -->
  <Component Id="MCManager.dll" Guid="8bd4b407-1ecb-40d7-b4c3-000000000001">
    <File Id="MCManager.dll" Source="..\..\bin\vc100\Win32\Release\MCManager.dll" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes"/>
  </Component>
  <Component Id="NavigationManager.dll" Guid="8bd4b407-1ecb-40d7-b4c3-000000000002">
    <File Id="NavigationManager.dll" Source="..\..\bin\vc100\Win32\Release\NavigationManager.dll" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes"/>
  </Component>
  <Component Id="MCTools.dll" Guid="8bd4b407-1ecb-40d7-b4c3-000000000003">
    <File Id="MCTools.dll" Source="..\..\bin\vc100\Win32\Release\MCTools.dll" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes"/>
  </Component>
```

The problem occurs with Telerik dll's, the other ones are copied in the first installation try correctly.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Check that the files installed in the new version of the installer have a higher file version than the same files installed by the old installer.

Comment: How can I set a new version for a file?? Thanks!

Comment: It's not something you would set within WiX, the files themselves will have their own version information. If you want WiX to ignore file versions and overwrite them no matter what, add the following line to your installer: <Property Id="REINSTALLMODE" Value="dmus" />

Comment: That works!!! Thanks a lot! @CalumMacLeod

Comment: I'll add the above as an answer so the question can be marked as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a problem with file versioning. For example, if a newer version of an installer tries to install lower-versioned files over higher-versioned ones, these files will be ignored. To get around this, you can add the following line to your WiX project to force the installer to always overwrite files if the versions are different, rather than only adding files if they are newer:

```
<Property Id="REINSTALLMODE" Value="dmus" />
```